# WPF Toolkit BarSeries descending order

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

Is it possible to set the sorting of WPF toolkit `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.BarSeries`? I have following bar chart:

```
<dvc:Chart x:Name="BarChart">
        <dvc:Chart.Axes>
            <dvc:CategoryAxis Orientation="X">
                <dvc:CategoryAxis.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dvc:CategoryAxis}" >
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform  Angle="-180" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </dvc:CategoryAxis.Style>
                <dvc:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                    <Style x:Name="labelStyleX1" TargetType="Control">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform  Angle="-45" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Style>
                </dvc:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
            </dvc:CategoryAxis>
        </dvc:Chart.Axes>
        <dvc:Chart.Series>
            <dvc:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Overall}"
                           DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"
                           IndependentValuePath="Key"
                           Title="Overall"
                           x:Name="overBar">
                <dvc:BarSeries.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dvc:BarSeries}" >
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform  Angle="-180" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </dvc:BarSeries.Style>
        </dvc:BarSeries>
</dvc:Chart.Series>
    </dvc:Chart>
```

Since `CategoryAxis.SortOrder` doesn't affect anything, I tried to manually rotate it by 180 degrees, but  axis doesn't rotate, leaving labels on the wrong places. The binded dictinary is definitely sorted, but this sorting is ignored by control:

```
Antecedent = new Dictionary<string, int>(Antecedent.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Take(MaxStats));
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594690/wpf-toolkit-chart-y-axis-descending-sort-order) solution, but it doesn't help. Though values are negated, sort order doesn't change:
[image]

How can I flip this series upside down, to have the most values at the top of the plot?

Answer (score 0):

You should sort values in ascending order not descending order.

Try to use `OrderBy` instead of `OrderByDescending`

```
Antecedent = new Dictionary<string, int>(Antecedent.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Take(MaxStats));
```

If it won't work then please share a code what you are assigning to `Overall` property because you are binding `ItemsSource` to `Overall` property.